# Dhtmlx scheduler lightbox control Event handler in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using DHTMLX scheduler in my MVC Application. In that light-box i need to use custom button . I have implemented the custom button successfully. I had share my code below.

In DTMLXscheduler.js

```
scheduler.config.buttons_left=["dhx_save_btn","dhx_cancel_btn","reminder_button"];

scheduler.locale.labels["reminder_button"] = "Location";
```

In DTMLXscheduler.css

```
.reminder_button_set{

     border: 1px solid #22A1BC;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #6f6f6f;
    background-color: #22A1BC;
}
```

I attached the eventhandler in Dhtmlxscheduler.js

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onLightboxButton", function (button_id, node, e) { if (button_id == "reminder_button") {alert("reminder") }}),
```

Here in event handler in the place of alert in need to call the  action controller of a view.

Is it possible to do this inside this event handler?

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in Advance.